# Debugging Push notification in mobilefirst 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I have a Liberty server farm over which **MobileFirst Platform 7.1** is deployed. I have deployed push notification adapters which is having a **Tag based notification** implementation. I have enabled the tracelogs using the below parameter in the **server.xml** file.

```
<logging  traceSpecification="com.ibm.ws.webcontainer*=all:com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer*=all:HTTPChannel=all"
traceFileName="trace.log"
maxFileSize="30"
maxFiles="20"
traceFormat="BASIC" />
```

How to confirm that the push notification has been sent to the GCM for the all numbers that are subscribed to a **Tag** using **trace.log**.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding "com.ibm.pushworks.*=all" to your trace specification will log messages regarding how Push is communicating with the GCF and APNS.

Comment: What is the size of the Image that can be sent in push notification

Answer (score 0):

you can turn on `Naming=all`for more info on this refer [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21143296#show-hide) or you can use

```
<logging traceSpecification="*=audit=enabled:com.worklight.integration.notification.*=finest=enabled" />
```